# PHP LDAP Authentication - Pound Symbel

Tags: php, ldap

I am using adLDAP.php to authenticate users against the AD server.

Users with £ (pound symbols) in their passwords cannot be authenticated.

Any £s in PHP vars get converted to "\xc2\xa3" £s in POST/GET vars get converted to "\xa3".

Is this a PHP/apache charset issue?

Comment: The incoming strings are UTF-8 then, while your LDAP expects Latin-1.

Comment: ok, looks like this like solves it all. Thanks. $password = mb_convert_encoding($_POST["password"], "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

$password = mb_convert_encoding($_POST["password"], "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$password = utf8_decode($password);
```

It worked for me (with a password containing "£" symbol).